# Multiple States in Xcode 6 Storyboard. Animating/Moving items in run time

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I have made various attempt to go storyboard only and limit my code when it comes to UI. Everytime I was getting stuck and reverting back to code. Since the release of XCode 6 and the new iPhone that have multiple screen sizes it make more sense that ever to go Storyboard only.

This time I am stuck on the following scenario. I want to create a custom search view controller that will have 2 states:

1. Search State. It will prompt the user for a keyword to search.
2. Result State. It will display the results to the user.

I am aware that this can be accomplished using the UISearchController, but the customer wants to customise the behaviour. Currently I have two view controllers and a push/show segue between them. I would like to replace that with one view controller and animate the display of the results.

Is there any way that storyboard can accomplish that. I am thinking of creating two view controllers (in storyboard) with different layouts. Both will be linked on the same class. I could create a segue between them, but then I will lose all the variable stored inside them and will not be able to animate between them.

On the transition between the two states some UI elements will be hidden and some others will be moved. I would like that to be animated.

I know how to do that in code without using storyboard, but then I will have to cover all different screen scenarios. I hope there is an alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two view controllers, and set a segue between them. The trick is that the animation bit will have to be done in code, unless you write a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` to handle the animation.

Comment: I am currently doing it this way but the animation is not correct and I get a new instance of the view controller.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as there is no other solution. I decided to go code only and do not use storyboards.